# Basic Authentication with IIS 6.0 and Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6

Is it possible to provide Basic authentication to clients using ASP.Net to authenticate the request in IIS 6.0 (I am pretty sure this is doable in 7.0 without much pain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bjorn has some source code that accomplishes this task.

http://blog.smithfamily.dk/2008/08/27/ImplementingBasicAuthenticationInASPNET20.aspx